# Area under probability density curve is not equal to 1

Tags: r

My model is based on the following growth function: x_t+1 = x_t + r * x_t * (1 – x_t/K)  The growth rate r is defined for each year by a random draw (mean=0.2, standard deviation=0.2). I am looking at the probability density function of the stock x after 70 years for 10000 runs. When I calculate the area under the probability density function, it is roughly equal to 1 for a standard deviation of 0.1 but not for a standard deviation of 0.2 or 0.3. I created a histogram for the area A with 100 values. It shows a very high peak at A=2 but the values for area even go up to 8. Why is it not equal to 1?

```
runs=10000

mean=0.2
sd=0.2

K=1
x_0=0.4
v=0.1
t=70

y=c()
x=x_0


for (j in 1:runs) {

rand=rnorm(t,mean,sd)

   for (i in 1:t) {

     x=max(x+rand[i]*x*(x-v)*(1-x/K),0)

     if(i==t)
       y[j]=x
    next}

  x=x_0
  next }

  library(sfsmisc)

  Dens=density(y)

  f=approxfun(Dens$x, Dens$y)

  h=c()

  i=seq(0.9, 1, length.out=100000)

      for (e in 1:length(i)) {
         h[e]=f(i[e])
      next}

  options(max.print=1000000) 

  h[is.na(h)]=0

  area=sum(abs(h[-1]+h[-length(h)])/2*diff(i))
```

Thank you!

Comment: What are you getting rather than 1? If it is close to 1 -- what do you expect? Numerical computations have round-off error.

Comment: it is most likely close to 2 but there are even some peaks in the histogram at 8 which cannot be a round-off error

Comment: What is the point of `library(sfsmisc)` ?

Comment: I copy pasted this part of the script and simplified it but I didn't check if the abovementioned library is still needed in the simplified version...

Answer (score 0):

You numerical integration is deeply flawed.

First of all, this is a plot of the density:

[image]

Almost all of the area is underneath an incredibly narrow, incredibly high spike. The overwhelming majority of your sample points are outside of that spike, hence don't do a very good job of estimating the area of that spike.

If you evaluate `print(Dens)` you see this:

```
Call:
    density.default(x = y)

Data: y (10000 obs.);   Bandwidth 'bw' = 1.734e-06

       x                y          
 Min.   :0.9922   Min.   :    0.0  
 1st Qu.:0.9942   1st Qu.:    0.0  
 Median :0.9961   Median :    0.0  
 Mean   :0.9961   Mean   :  439.1  
 3rd Qu.:0.9981   3rd Qu.:    0.0  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :91131.2
```

Note in particular the *all* of the x values are > 0.99, but you are using a numerical integration over the interval [.9,1]. Thus, most of your numerical integration is outside of the range of the density. You are using (via `approxfun`) *extrapolated* values in the range [0.9, 0.99], and extrapolating far outside (relatively speaking) the range of the data. Thus 90% of your numerical integration is based on an unreliable extrapolation of two almost-zero values (the first two y values).

You need to find some way to rescale the data. The call to `density` itself is problematic. It uses (as a default) 512 points, but if you look at them, only a few dozen have `y` values that are significantly greater than 0. You are trying to get a picture of a distribution by mostly sampling the tails rather than the values where something significant is happening.